# Why does this piece of code not function. It appears with cant assign to operator error

Tags: python-3.x

Why does this not work

```
Name=input
Class=input
(Name+Class)=[]
Time=input
(Name+Class).append(Time)
```

I am new to python so I am still learning the basics
For this piece of code I want it to create a new list each time different data for Name and Class is inputed

Comment: What in the name of god are you trying to do...

Comment: I want to use (Name+Class) as the name of a list e.g if Name=me and Class= D it would be like meD.append

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would strongly recommend you to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). Anyway, your snippet might work like this:

```
Name = input('Enter name:\n')    # input is a function 
Class = input('Enter class:\n')  # hence parentheses
Time = input('Enter time:\n')    # and an (here: optional) argument, the prompt

l = [Name, Class, Time]  # now works: l.append(sth)
```